# How can i permanently get rid of snow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

At the moment I'm building an extremely humongous mansion and I don't want it covered in snow. It is so annoying when it randomly starts snowing. I don't want to have to keep stopping and getting rid of the snow in chat, I want it permanently gone.

Is it possible to  permanently get rid of snow while I am building?

Comment: i don't have the latest version of minecraft but in at least 1.7.10 snow wont form on the top of blocks surrounding a source of heat like a torch

Comment: What about /gamerule doWeatherCycle false and then /weather clear?

Comment: I just like you. A lot. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on whether you have creative mode, cheats, and command blocks, you have a handful of options. There are still a few options if you have none of these.

1. Have a command block run the command `/weather clear` constantly.
2. For a little less lag, have a command block set up to run when it receives a redstone pulse from a daylight sensor `/weather clear 24000`, which will once per day set the weather to be clear for one day.
3. Lots of torches everywhere. I understand that this approach can make your build look tacky depending on what aesthetic you're going for.
4. Incorporate lots of glowstone within your design. They double as a great light source to keep mobs away as well.
5. Have redstone contraptions release water on a timer once or twice per day. This can be done either by hiding a water source block and revealing it with a piston, or having a water bucket in a dispenser. Combine with a daylight sensor and pulse shortener, for example, and you get automatic snow clearing in the path of the water. Be sure to give the water someplace to run to so you can still navigate your property while it is running.
6. Make water or lava part of the design of your property. Lava can be concealed behind glass blocks to stop it from setting wood on fire. Also serves double duty as a light source, like the glowstone. Having your floors be made of glass with lava underneath always looks awesome, if you can stand the constant bubbling sound.
7. Use lots of half slabs or stairs in your build. Snow can't accumulate on them, so if you make your pathways out of [one of the slabs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slab), and only have them occupy the bottom half of their block, you get seamless looking ground that can't have snow on it.
8. As SpiceWeasel suggested in comments, just run the command `/gamerule doWeatherCycle false` once, and `/weather clear` once, which will stop weather altogether in all biomes.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you could do this.

1. Light up the area you want to rid of snow.
2. Use the command /gamerule doWeatherCycle false
3. Use slabs to cover the top of it.  Snow can't fall on the bottom half of a block.

Hope this helped.

NathanielSantley

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what permissions you have, several options exist:

- If you can use cheats -- `gamerule doWeatherCycle false` then `/weather clear`
- If you have creative mode -- build a ceiling of barrier blocks
- If you have neither -- build a ceiling or a layer of string

You could also just build lower and in a different biome!